# Directive interacting with rootScope not working in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to interact with the `rootScope` in order to make a modal appear. I have a very basic directive that I am trying to use `rootScope` paired with an `ng-show`.

Here is the code for the directive:

```
.directive('modal', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'view/templates/modal-confirm.tpl.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope);

            element.on('click', function() {
                scope.$root.confirmModal.isVisible = true;
                console.log('open modal');
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

When I log the `scope` variable, it is showing me as having `$root` updated with the `isVisible: true` however, my modal doesn't appear. If I change the `scope.$root.confirmModal.isVisible = true;` to `$rootScope.confirmModal.isVisible = true;` I get the same result, the console.log is working but no modal appearing.

This is the code for the modal template:

```
<!-- Confirm Modal Template -->
<div ng-if="$root.confirmModal.isVisible" class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content extended">
        <span>{{ $root.confirmModal.content }}</span>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button ng-click="$root.confirmModal.isVisible = false;" class="btn btn-default half">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it not possible to interact with the `$rootScope` in a directive?

Updated code using `scope` instead of `$rootScope`:

```
.directive('modal', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'view/templates/modal-confirm.tpl.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.isVisible = false;

            element.on('click', function() {
                scope.isVisible = true;
                console.log(scope);
                console.log('open modal');
            });
        }
    }
}])

<!-- Confirm Modal Template -->
<div ng-if="isVisible" class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content extended">
        <span>hello world</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same result however.

Comment: why do you need to do this on rootScope?

Comment: If I change `scope.$root.confirmModal.isVisible` to just `scope.isVisible` and `$root.confirmModal.isVisible` to `isVisible`, init with `scope.isVisible = false;` it does not appear on click. It is being set to `isVisible: true` if I look at the `scope` after the on-click function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing something wrong you are just missing one line of code. In this statement :

```
element.on('click', function() {
  scope.isVisible = true;
  console.log(scope);
  console.log('open modal');
});
```

you are creating an anonymous function, which is perfectly fine, but angular will not be able to auto magically track changes made to scope variables.What you need to do is to explicitly request for a digest cycle at the end of your function either with wrapping your code within $apply or $timeout function. Like so :

```
element.on('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function(){ // or $timeout(function() {
    scope.isVisible = true;
    console.log(scope);
    console.log('open modal');
  });

});
```

If you want to know more about $apply check this [great article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html). Finally I have assemble a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z3dr73geXeglfei7Qp2J?p=preview) with your code for you to be able to test.